# JPA save or merge, how to know updated fields

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, orm

How can I know what fields/columns are updated after an object is saved by jpa/hibernate. I know there is a interceptor to do this, but cannot find what it is. need some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the @EntityListener you are looking for? Take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html)